# Voltage-gated calcium (Ca2+) channels

Tags: calcium

My question is related to "voltage-gated calcium (Ca2+) channels". I don't really have a background in chemistry or biology other than basic elementary school knowledge so I'm a little confused about what kind of reactions need to take place (if any) to form the calcium cations that activate these channels. Do any calcium compounds that contain a calcium ion as part of the bond work to regulate the channels (such as the calcium found in milk) or do they have to be broken down into single calcium ions or form into specific calcium ionic compounds before they can be used for channel regulation?

Comment: Probably makes more sense to work on the background in chemistry and biology. In this case you want to learn what it means for an ionic compound to dissolve in water. Also voltage gated calcium channels aren't activated by calcium they are activated by voltage, that's why they're called voltage-gated.

Comment: Don't ions carry a charge? Where else does the "voltage" or potential difference come from? I'm assuming It takes a certain amount of charged ions to create the voltage levels necessary to open or close the gates.

Comment: You need a broader picture. I'd start with a neuroscience textbook like Purves Neuroscience or Kandel Principles of Neural Science. StackExchange is good for specific questions; it's not a good way to learn a topic backwards by starting with a question far from your understanding and working backwards to back fill.

Comment: If you explain why you're asking the question/what you're trying to achieve, it's possible someone can help you with that, but if you're trying to understand how neurotransmission works you should start from scratch.